# Can't authenticate for REST testing

Tags: yii2, codeception

I have the following virtual host name setup on xampp: `reporting.dev`

```
public function userIsAuthenticated(\ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->amGoingTo('Check Authentication works');
        // i've tried both of these ways to authenticate
        $I->amHttpAuthenticated('my_email', 'my_password');
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Basic super_long_token');
        $I->sendGET(Url::toRoute('/api/reports', true)); 
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
        $I->deleteHeader('Authorization');
    }
```

The following request works in postman `http://reporting.dev/api/reports` using a Basic Auth header and the same token in the test above.

This is my api suite config:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
      - REST:
          depends: PhpBrowser
          #url: /api/
          part: Json
      - Yii2:
          part: [orm, fixtures]
          configFile: 'config/web.php'
```

I'm using Yii2, if I remove the behaviors function from my api controller that determines the authentication as Basic Auth, I then do get a 200 response and the expected json.

```
public function behaviors()
  {
      $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
      $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
          'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
          'except' => [], 
      ];
      return $behaviors;
  }
```

So I'm unsure what else I can do here or why I'm not authenticated

Comment: amHttpAuthenticated method of PhpBrowser (and REST when PhpBrowser is used) sets Authorization header, so setting it with haveHttpHeader is redundant and potentially causing an issue.

Comment: I deleted comments about conflicting modules, because you have the right parts enabled.

Comment: @Naktibalda So what do you suggest, I've tried them both individually and I get 401s

Comment: echo base64_decode('token'); and check if you get the same email and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had here was the auth token I have in my DB was not base64 encoded.

```
public function userIsAuthenticated(\ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->amGoingTo('Check Authentication works');
    // fixed now 
    $I->haveHttpHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' . base64_encode('Basic super_long_db_auth_token'));
    $I->sendGET(Url::toRoute('/api/reports', true)); 
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(\Codeception\Util\HttpCode::OK); // 200
    $I->deleteHeader('Authorization');
}
```

Comment: The header can be represented like that `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side

Comment: I know. That's part of how the header is represented `Basic  token`

Comment: No, I have the word `'Basic '` prefixed to the base64_encoded token. Because it's need. The tests fail without it. That's why I referenced the wiki article. All the requests postman builds across multiple languages also prefix this :-)